# Create small file with dates and timestamps from c++ api

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to create, from a c++ program, a .parquet file as small as possible.

I would like to use the `parquet::StreamWriter`.

TL;DR: What are the best compression / encoder settings and how should the columns (`parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode`) be declared to get the smallest file?

It should be possible to get a file roughly the same size of a csv with the same data compressed with gzip.

My file contains a date, a datetime (or timestamp I guess), an integer and a float per row. It will have to be opened from r and the date and timestamp have to be datetimes without transforming the column afterwards.

For the time being I'm setting the date as a timestamp. I think I am being a bit thick, but I don't get the docs: https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md, and in the tests and examples: https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/blob/master/src/parquet/arrow/arrow-reader-writer-test.cc there seems to be nothing like this, oddly enough.

A toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "arrow/io/file.h"
#include "parquet/stream_writer.h"

int main() {
    for (auto i : std::vector<int>({1, 2})) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::string id("_gzip_compressor_delta_binary_packet_encoding");
        std::shared_ptr<::arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
        std::string file_path = "/tmp/test." + std::to_string(i) + id + ".parquet";
        PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(outfile, ::arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(file_path))
        parquet::schema::NodeVector columns {};
        columns.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make("integer", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED,
                                                               parquet::Type::INT64, parquet::ConvertedType::UINT_64));
        columns.push_back(
            parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make("float", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, parquet::Type::FLOAT));
        columns.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make("timestamp", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED,
                                                               parquet::Type::INT64,
                                                               parquet::ConvertedType::TIMESTAMP_MILLIS));
        columns.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make("date_as_timestamp", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED,
                                                               parquet::Type::INT64,
                                                               parquet::ConvertedType::TIMESTAMP_MILLIS));

        auto schema = std::static_pointer_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode>(
            parquet::schema::GroupNode::Make("schema", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, columns));
        parquet::WriterProperties::Builder builder;
        builder.compression(parquet::Compression::GZIP);
        builder.encoding(parquet::Encoding::DELTA_BINARY_PACKED);
        parquet::StreamWriter parquet_writer {parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(outfile, schema, builder.build())};

        std::ofstream csv_file("/tmp/test." + std::to_string(i) + ".csv");
        for (uint64_t number = 1; number <= 1000000; ++number) {
            parquet_writer << number;
            float float_number(number * 0.5);
            parquet_writer << float_number;
            std::chrono::milliseconds timestamp{1000ull + number};
            parquet_writer << timestamp;
            std::chrono::milliseconds date_as_timestamp{1000ull + number};
            parquet_writer << date_as_timestamp << parquet::EndRow;
            csv_file << number << std::endl;
        }
        csv_file.close();
        parquet_writer.EndRowGroup();
    }
    std::cout << "Ended ok" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The sizes I'm getting are:

```
    6888896 may 22 12:35 test.1.csv
    6888896 may 22 12:35 test.2.csv
    6859569 may 22 13:06 test.1_gzip_compressor_delta_binary_packet_encoding.parquet
    6859569 may 22 13:06 test.2_gzip_compressor_delta_binary_packet_encoding.parquet
```

Compressing with `gzip -k test.2.csv`:

```
    2129154 may 22 13:06 test.2.csv.gz
```

Opening and saving with r (`saveRDS`):

```
    8925791 may 22 13:11 test.1.rds
```

I have tried several compression and encoding settings with little success... I am pretty sure I am messing up with the date and timestamp, because if I only use an integer column I get a very reasonable output.

Example of output:

> df <- read_parquet("/tmp/test.1_gzip_compressor_delta_binary_packet_encoding.parquet")
> head(df)

```
  integer float           timestamp   date_as_timestamp
1       1   0.5 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
2       2   1.0 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
3       3   1.5 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
4       4   2.0 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
5       5   2.5 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
6       6   3.0 1970-01-01 00:00:01 1970-01-01 00:00:01
```

Comment: Please show us a couple of lines of your uncompressed output.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the original question, I don't seem to be able to get the output correctly formatted in a comment.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I don't have the know-how to help you I'm afraid, but others might.  That data certainly looks like it should compress well.

Comment: If size is a concern you should try to use `parquet::ConvertedType::DATE` for the date column (it only uses 32 bits instead of 64). Also you are not doing a fair comparison of the csv file vs parquet. It looks like your csv file only contain the number (and not the integre, timestamp, date_as_timestamp)

Comment: At the time of writing this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/parquet.html#encodings seems to indicate that writing with `parquet::Encoding::DELTA_BINARY_PACKED` is not supported and as such that option is likely not doing what you think it is. Instead it is likely using the `RLE_DICTIONARY` encoding type.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing about the csv, @0x26res. I have tried using DATE as converted type for the column without hours, minutes and seconds, but so far I haven't been able to make it work (it compiles, but then I get some bizarre error). Will keep trying.

Comment: Thanks, @cogle, I thought I had tried every encoding, but maybe I missed this one. I will try.